# Ubuntu 14.04 two screens but separately X session

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi

I have a Skylake i7 that has a onboard video card that have VGA, DVI and HDMI outputs. If I connect a monitor to HDMI and one to DVI or VGA only one X display is created ( DISPLAY :0 ).

How can I have separate X display for each output ? Like :0 , :1 , :2 for example.

I need this to open application on specific display ( use export DISPLAY=:1 for example ).

Also I don't want any icons/menu/etc... on secondary displays.

How can this be achieved ?

Thanks !